# 0 packages available to be installed in Anaconda Navigator base environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

[image: 1]

I am trying to install packages in my base(root) environment using the anaconda navigator. However, there is no any packages available to be installed. I can install using the anaconda cmd but the GUI navivgator could be much easier. Can you please help me with solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and they're working on it:

https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/anaconda-navigator-not-installed-packages-bug/50292/3

Near term solution is to roll back to conda 22.9.